# Parse .NET Code to Call Tree

Tags: .net, codedom

I have quite a few programs with same- or similar-named functions that I have been moving to a library.  I am not using any code check-in software, just sub-folders for each project.  I have been using a plain-text file search to find the files with these libraried functions.

I could write a program to read in the lines and compile the list of " FUNCTION " definition names.  I would like to know if there is a way to use System.CodeDom's CompileAssemblyFromSource and Reflection to parse the .NET code files and list the Namespace / Class / Function definition tree contained therein.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might find www.ndepend.com useful for this sort of task.

Comment: It turns out that CompileAssemblyFromFile works with command-line programs, not WinForms.  I can use the result from the compilation to get CompiledAssembly.GetExportedTypes.GetMethods.  This is close enough for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the sort of thing [Microsoft Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) can help you with.